# Getting value from user with textInput and assigning to variable (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

Here I want to assign the data from textInput to variable a. How can I do it?
(That is, when the user enters data in textInput, I want to assign it to variable a.)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, TextInput} from 'react-native'

export default class deneme1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

            a:"",
            
       };
      }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={styles.textinput}>
                    <TextInput
                    placeholderTextColor='white'
                    style={styles.textinputtext}
                />

                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one

```
<TextInput
 placeholder={"A Variable"}
 onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({a: text}) }
 value={this.state.a}
/>
```